# How can I scroll a ListView by one row instead of the default three using the mouse wheel?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I have a modified ListView. When I scroll using the mouse wheel, it scrolls three rows.

I want it to scroll one row at a time using the mouse wheel.

```
Public Class listviewEx
Inherits ListView
    Private Declare Function ShowScrollBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wBar As Integer,
    ByVal bShow As Boolean) As Integer
    ' Constants
    Private Const SB_HORZ As Integer = 0

    Private Const WM_HSCROLL As Integer = &H114
    Private Const WM_VSCROLL As Integer = &H115

    Public Event Scroll As ScrollEventHandler


    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        ShowScrollBar(MyBase.Handle, SB_HORZ, False)
        If m.Msg = &H115 Then
            ' Trap WM_VSCROLL
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, True)
     End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ShowScrollbar() is done for different reason. Is there a way i can override the default scroll on my listview to scroll by 1? Do you have any example ? If not, no worries i appreciate your time. I know it's unusual request. Its just the list view height is not big enough to scroll by 3 rows at once.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a behavior to your ListView, to make it scroll one row instead of the default three, using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (as this modifier is often used to change this kind of behaviors) in combination with the mouse wheel.

You can then have the standard three-rows scroll when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not pressed and one-row scroll behavior when it's pressed.

Override WndProc (as you're already doing), to handle [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousewheel) and verify that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed, checking whether the low-word of WParam is `MK_CONTROL = &H08`.

When it's pressed, determine whether the delta is positive or negative and increment the value returned by [ListView.TopItem.Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.index) to then set the [TopItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.topitem) based on the calculated offset (adding a minimum/maximum check to avoid overflows):

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class ListViewEx
    Inherits ListView

    Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL As Integer = &H20A
    Private Const MK_CONTROL As Integer = &H8

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                If Items.Count > 0 AndAlso (m.WParam.ToInt64() And &HFF) = MK_CONTROL Then
                    Dim offset = If((m.WParam.ToInt64() >> 16) > 0, -1, 1) + TopItem.Index
                    offset = Math.Max(Math.Min(offset, Items.Count - 1), 0)
                    TopItem = Items(offset)
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Jimi. I tried it. It won't override it. What do you think of the solution that i posted it. That solution worked? Someone else did it.

Comment: I copied it and paste it as is with no additional code. It kept scrolling by 3 using the mouse wheel

Comment: I didn't do the Control. I just want it to be scrol by 1 without the control.

Comment: It does work with pressing the control lol

Comment: If you don't want to use the `CONTROL + MOUSEWHEEL` combination, just remove the `If (m.WParam.ToInt64() And &HFF) = MK_CONTROL Then ...` condition, so it will do it in any case.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your time. Hopefully it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Someone named Viorel did it:

```
Public Class listviewEx
    Inherits ListView

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)

        Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL = &H20A

        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                If TopItem IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim d As Int16 = (m.WParam.ToInt32 >> 16)
                    Dim i As Integer

                    If d > 0 Then
                        i = Math.Max(TopItem.Index - 1, 0)
                    Else
                        i = Math.Min(TopItem.Index + 1, Items.Count - 1)

                    End If

                    TopItem = Items(i)
                End If

                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero

                Return

        End Select

        MyBase.WndProc(m)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That *may* constitute plagiarism. Can you provide a more accurate reference? For example, a link (URL).