# How to select the back row and the back row of a DataGridView with the mouse scroll?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a DataGridView that is filled with the database via SqlServer. then I need to manipulate the DataGridView lines with the mouse scroll just like I manipulate with the navigation arrows. I searched in many places but I was not successful. Does anyone have any ideas or ways to help me?

I need something like this:

mouse scroll down
datagridview.rows.select +1

mouse scroll up
datagridview.rows.select -1

And the scroll bar will go along with the e.RowIndex line

Comment: Try to tweak [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66991960/14171304) solution to work with DGV. Use the [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex) property to set the top row.

Comment: I can solve the problem in a simpler way, but thanks to the help of your clear example, dr.null thanks.

Comment: What is simpler than `DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex).Selected = True`

Comment: Well, I tried to do with:
 FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
 and fail. In the solution it worked I posted it worked, @Mary 
put your way and I will test in the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve the problem in a simpler way, but thanks to the help of your clear example, dr.null thanks.

using using datagridview MouseWheel, stayed that way:

```
       Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseWheel
    CType(e, HandledMouseEventArgs).Handled = True
    If e.Delta < 0 Then
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}")
    Else
        SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
    End If
      End Sub
```

an interesting detail:

```
              CType (e, HandledMouseEventArgs) .Handled = True
```

Prevents the scroll from moving until it is at the top or the beginning of the screen.

Comment: What if the user scrolls using the thumb or the up and down arrows of the scroll bar instead of the mouse wheel?

Comment: I believe that the arrows by default already work, I don't have much experience